# Is there a plans for adding something like C#'s Expression Trees in future Java releases?

Tags: java, expression-trees

C# has really cool thing like [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). To my mind this feature would be extremely useful in Java but I haven't heard talks about plans of adding something like this to Java.

I am curious about whether there is some discussion in Java-language community about adding something like this in future Java releases, Java 8/9 possibly?

Comment: If this sort of programming paradigm is particularly useful to you, consider implementing part of your codebase in Scala, which is interoperable with Java.

Comment: I doubt we will see literal expression trees (i.e., lambdas emitted as expression trees instead of compiled delegates).  But if all you want is to be able to compose expressions programatically for the purposes of code generation, [there is an implementation](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/) of the LINQ expression tree API and compiler for Java.